# LocationManager crash when no city found from geocoordinates

Tags: java, android, locationmanager, reverse-geocoding

I'm using Locationmanager to obtain users GeoPoints then convert it to city / state. The issue is that some users 'crash' when this happens, and when I take out the geopoint to city conversion as seen below they don't crash. So I pinpointed that, and I assume it returns null for some people depending on their geocoordinates. **Is there a more reliable way to obtaining someones City if I absolutely need it?**

```
public class UserLocation implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            if (loc != null)
            {

                mLatitude = loc.getLatitude();
                mLongitude = loc.getLongitude();
                Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses;
                try {
                    addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(mLatitude, mLongitude, 10);
                     int i=1;
                     for(Address addObj:addresses)
                     {
                         // Looping once
                         if(i==1)
                         { 

                             //Setting city
                             mCity = addObj.getSubLocality();                            
                             //setting state
                             mState = returnStateAbbreviation(addObj.getAdminArea());


                             i++;
                         }
                     }
                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }}
            else
            {
                Log.i(mTag, "No location found, hrmp?");
            }
            // Stopping Location Updates
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
        }
```

Or would it be easier to just compare 2 geo points to display a distance between them to list rather then a city and state?

Comment: http://ideone.com/3jIeRB : from docs: `getFromLocation`  - "Returns
a list of Address objects. **Returns null** or empty list ... **edit:** title is misleading

Comment: Do you have the logcat for one of those crashes?

Comment: I took both your advice and just checked if it was null first, then cycled through to getLocality, if thats null as well I just use a custom string 'Near by'. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Selvin said, getFromLocation can return null according to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int))

> Returns
>   a list of Address objects. Returns **null or empty list** if no matches were found or there is no backend service available.

You need to check if it's null before you loop through the addresses

```
addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(mLatitude, mLongitude, 10);
if (addresses != null) {
    int i=1;
    for(Address addObj:addresses)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Regarding your second question, it depends on what you want to do but calculating the distance between two points is easy. You could use [this Location method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]))

```
public static void distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)
```